# Proper syntax for using type <T> in function signature

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a correct way of changing this function signature:

```
 private IEnumerable<ViewPatient> TransformViewPatient(IOrderedQueryable<view_patient> query);
```

to something like?

```
 private IEnumerable<ViewPatient> TransformViewPatient<T>(T query)
```

where T is

```
IOrderedQueryable<view_patient>
```

Edit: I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
 private IEnumerable<ViewPatient> TransformViewPatient<ObjectResult<view_patient>>(ObjectResult<view_patient> query)
```

and

```
 private IEnumerable<ViewPatient> TransformViewPatient<IOrderedQueryable<view_patient>>(IOrderedQueryable<view_patient> query)
```

Comment: `ViewPatient`, `view_patient` or both?

Comment: @abatishchev   just to view_patient. Thanks.

Comment: I mean how many types do you have?

Comment: @abatishchev  I misunderstood. Only need the IOrderQueryable<view_patient> type brought out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<T> TransformViewPatient<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> query)
    where T : ViewPatient
```

or wider

```
IQueryable<T> TransformViewPatient<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    where T : ViewPatient
```

or wider

```
IEnumerable<T> TransformViewPatient<T>(IEnumerable<T> query)
    where T : ViewPatient
```

---

If you have 2 different types then:

```
IQueryable<T> TransformViewPatient<T, U>(IQueryable<U> query)
    where T : ViewPatient
    where U : view_patient
```

P.S.

`view_patient` is really bad name for a class.

Update:

If you want want to have a generic collection then:

```
IEnumerable<T> TransformViewPatient<T, TColl>(TColl query)
    where T : ViewPatient
    where TColl : IQuerable<T>
```

Comment: Please see my edit. Can the "IQueryable" part be brought out? Thanks?

Comment: @AlanWayne: see the update. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Probably.  Let me test it. Why is "T" with "TColl" in the function generic of <T, TColl> ?  Should this not just be <TColl> ??

Comment: @AlanWayne: You can remove `T` if it's always the same type. Also depdens whether or not [TColl is covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).